# ActiveJDBC complex queries

Tags: activejdbc

How can I make a complex query with ActiveJDBC?

I have a model `Student` and a model `Class`

```
Student:
   id
   first_name
   last_name


Class:
   id
   name
   student_id
```

I'm given two student ids 1 and 50 for example

I want to get all the classes such that the student id is between 1 and 50 and such that the first name matches "Dan"

I know I can do the following to get the list of classes between student id [1 - 50]:

```
List<Class> classesList = Class.where("student_id >= ? and student_id <= ?", firstStudent.getId(), SecondStudent.getId());
```

but then how I do restrict the student name?

I also have requirements to make more complex queries (specially with many-to-many models) but I'm not sure how to get around it with ActiveJDBC

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to restrict to first name "Dan":

```
List<Class> classesList = Class.where("student_id >= ? and student_id <= ? and first_name = ?", firstStudent.getId(), SecondStudent.getId(), "Dan");
```

For many-to-many you need to provide more details to get help

Comment: the student name is only in the Student model and not the Class model though

Comment: In that case you need to write a free-hand SQL:

`List<Class> classesList = Class.findBySql("select * from classes, students where  classes.student_id >= ? and classes.student_id <= ? and students.id = classes.student_id and students.first_name = ?", firstStudent.getId(), SecondStudent.getId(), "Dan");`